# Centre item in menu in Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Using semantic UI to make a navbar at the top of my page. I would like some items to be left floated, others to be right floated, and one (the website name) to be centered. How can I go about this?

```
    <div class="ui teal fixed inverted menu compact">
        <div class="ui container sequenced1">

            <a href="/jobs" class="item">Home</a>

            <div class="header item">Centered Name</div>
            <a href="/login" class="item ui right floated">Login</a>
            <a href="/register" class="item">Sign up</a>
            <a class="item ui right floated">Signed in as 
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: How about this one 
https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/NwGGJJ

Comment: Wait no sorry. It places the logo in the center of the left floated and right floated objects. I need it to be in the center of the page.